# Trouble Creating Text Node in Head via JS Self-Executing Function

Tags: javascript, appendchild, self-executing-function, createtextnode

This is the first time that I am working with self-executing anonymous functions, however, I believe that I am missing something that is both fundamental and right in front of my face. Essentially, I am attempting to pass an argument through the function 'writeFontFace()' and have it write the following code inside the head of my document, like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arrows';
    src: url('fonts/arrows/arrows.eot?');
    src: url('fonts/arrows/arrows.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/arrows/arrows.woff?') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/arrows/arrows.ttf?') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/arrows/arrows.svg?#arrows') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Now, if I un-comment the 'return' statement at the end of this function (writeFontFace) I do receive the appropriate output that I am expecting to receive, however (for whatever reason), it is not appending the 'script' variable (containing the aforementioned @font-face definition) inside of the head of my document? Can't quite figure out why. Any suggestions and/or comments would surely be appreciated... And again, this is my first time working with self-executing anonymous functions, therefore, I would appreciate a low level of sarcasm if anyone feels as though they might have some constructive criticism and/or advice. As always, much appreciation in advance.

~ Cheers

- Self-Executing Anonymous Function

  ```
  (function() {

       /**
        * Object Literal           {Property Values}           Constant: property values to be used throughout this object
        */
        const vars = {
             decCharPrefix : '&#',
             decCharSuffix : ';',
             baseGlyphValue: 59392,
           }
       };

       /**
        * bpIconFont               {Constructor}               Core: constructor for this library; ensures that this library is instantiated if an internal method is called
        */
       var bpIconFont = function() {
           if(!(this instanceof bpIconFont))
               return new bpIconFont();
       };

       /**
        * bpIconFont.fn
        */
       bpIconFont.fn = bpIconFont.prototype = {
           init: function() {
               console.log('bpIconFont Initialized!');
           }
       }

       window.bpIconFont = bpIconFont;                         // Expose: anonymous self-executing function to DOM

  })();

  /**
   * getFontDirectroy         {Method}                    Gets: generates the directory to which the passed font will be placed, via relative path
   * @param                   {Array/String} font         Converts: the passed array or string and generates a 'relative path' for the desired font
   * @return                  {Array/String}              Returns: the relative path for the font
   */
  bpIconFont.fn.getFontDirectroy = function(font) {
      var fontDir = 'fonts/' + font + '/';
      return fontDir;
  };

  /**
   * getFontDirectroy         {Method}                    Gets: generates the directory to which the passed font will be placed, via relative path
   * @param                   {Array/String} font         Converts: the passed array or string and generates a 'relative path' for the desired font
   * @return                  {Array/String}              Returns: the relative path for the font
   */
  bpIconFont.fn.writeFontFace = function(font) {
      var dir    = bpIconFont().getFontDirectroy(font);
      var head   = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
      var script = document.createElement('style');
          script.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');

      var fontFace = '@font-face {' +
                    '\n\tfont-family: \'' + font +
                  '\';\n\tsrc: url(\'' + dir + font + '.eot?\');' +
                     '\n\tsrc: url(\'' + dir + font + '.eot?#iefix\') format(\'embedded-opentype\'),' +
                       '\n\t\t url(\'' + dir + font + '.woff?\') format(\'woff\'),' +
                       '\n\t\t url(\'' + dir + font + '.ttf?\') format(\'truetype\'),' +
                       '\n\t\t url(\'' + dir + font + '.svg?#' + font + '\') format(\'svg\');' +
                     '\n\tfont-weight: normal;' +
                     '\n\tfont-style: normal;' +
                  '\n}';

      script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fontFace));

      head.appendChild(script);

      // return fontFace;
  };
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, if anyone else runs into a similar problem, the code below should supply you with the appropriate fix:

```
(function() {

     /**
      * bpIconFont               {Constructor}               Core: constructor for this library; ensures that this library is instantiated if an internal method is called
      */
     var bpIconFont = function() {
         if(!(this instanceof bpIconFont))
         return new bpIconFont();
     };

     /**
      * bpIconFont.fn
      */
     bpIconFont.fn = bpIconFont.prototype = {
         init: function() {
             console.log('bpIconFont Initialized!');
         }
     }

     window.bpIconFont = bpIconFont;                         // Expose: anonymous self-executing function to DOM

})();

     /**
      * Object Literal           {Property Values}           Constant: property values to be used throughout this object
      */
    vars = {
        decCharPrefix : '&#',
        decCharSuffix : ';',
        baseGlyphValue: 59392,
    };

/**
 * getFontDirectroy         {Method}                    Gets: generates the directory to which the passed font will be placed, via relative path
 * @param                   {Array/String} font         Converts: the passed array or string and generates a 'relative path' for the desired font
 * @return                  {Array/String}              Returns: the relative path for the font
 */
bpIconFont.fn.getFontDirectroy = function(font) {
    var fontDir = 'fonts/' + font + '/';
    return fontDir;
};

/**
 * getFontDirectroy         {Method}                    Gets: generates the directory to which the passed font will be placed, via relative path
 * @param                   {Array/String} font         Converts: the passed array or string and generates a 'relative path' for the desired font
 * @return                  {Array/String}              Returns: the relative path for the font
 */
bpIconFont.fn.writeFontFace = function(font) {
    var dir    = bpIconFont().getFontDirectroy(font);
    var head   = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement('style');
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');

    var cssDef = '\ndiv#output-window {' +
                 '\n\tfont-family:\'' + font + '\';' +
                 '\n}';

    var fontFace = '@font-face {' +
                  '\n\tfont-family: \'' + font +
                '\';\n\tsrc: url(\'' + dir + font + '.eot?\');' +
                   '\n\tsrc: url(\'' + dir + font + '.eot?#iefix\') format(\'embedded-opentype\'),' +
                     '\n\t\t url(\'' + dir + font + '.woff?\') format(\'woff\'),' +
                     '\n\t\t url(\'' + dir + font + '.ttf?\') format(\'truetype\'),' +
                     '\n\t\t url(\'' + dir + font + '.svg?#' + font + '\') format(\'svg\');' +
                   '\n\tfont-weight: normal;' +
                   '\n\tfont-style: normal;' +
                '\n}';

    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fontFace));
    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cssDef));
    head.appendChild(script);

};
```